# What's the difference between around the clock and 24/7?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I found their definitions very similar. They both mean nonstop. Are they exactly synonymous or there are some differences?

Comment: "We worked around the clock to get it done" does not mean "for a week", or even  "never-ending". Also [rock around the clock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbYiGR0YAAk) means (or meant) "dance all night".

Comment: If you accept the answer I get some Internet points ...

Answer (score 3):

As the comments already suggest, there is a subtle difference, which is how long they imply an action goes on for.

**Around the clock** means ***without ceasing**, even during the night when most normal activity ceases*. It can (and usually does) mean that one or people stayed up all night, but can also mean a larger collection (say, the workforce of a factory or the staff at a consulate or legal firm) *between them* worked “all hours”. It may not be completely literal (factories may have short pauses during shift changes, for example; lawyers may order coffee).

**24/7** (as @user121863 and @weather-vane pointed out) has a stronger connotation that not only does the activity continue ***all day, every day** [of the week]* – implying *for more than a week* – but (by usually not mentioning an individual week) implies that this is the pattern *every* week. If a time period *is* mentioned, it indicates that the pattern (no hour excluded, no day excluded) continued throughout that period.

In normal English usage, both mean ***non-stop***, but typically the first is used for *worked without stopping to meet a deadline*, and the second for *the lights never went out; the people and the machines kept moving hour after hour, day after day…*.